# Serial communication API for Java on 64 bit systems (modem interaction)

Tags: java, serial-port, 32bit-64bit, modem, rxtx

I'm searching for an serial communication API for Java. Very important is the support of 64 bit systems. I've used rxtx with the 64 bit libs of [Cloudhopper](http://www.cloudhopper.com/opensource/rxtx/) but on some Windows Server 2008 systems I got heavy problems with jvm crashes when accessing (virtual) serial ports.

The main purpose is interacting with analogue modems, maybe there is another way of modem communication in Java?

It would be very nice if the API is free of charge.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have moved to the new [java-simple-serial-connector](http://code.google.com/p/java-simple-serial-connector/) which seems to be very stable and comfortable at the current release 0.9.0. For now it works on every system (I need) and has no problem with virtual serial ports.

Answer (score 2):

You can try [Java Communications API](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/index-jsp-141752.html).

You can configure it using help from this [link](http://circuitnegma.wordpress.com/2007/02/07/how-to-install-the-java-communications-api-in-a-windows-environment/).

**EDIT**:

Download it from [here](http://rickproctor.wordpress.com/2006/06/07/javaxcomm-jar-for-windows-mia/).

Comment: Thank you, but I believed that Java Communications API doesn't support 64 bit systems.

Comment: I'm using it in my Application on 64-bit Windows 7. API version 3.0 does not support Windows but you can use previous version.